# How to resize a JPanel based on its parent container's size

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I tried using BoxLayout because that's the layout that supports the centered vertical stacking of panels that I'm trying to achieve. 
The problem is that when I don't set the maximum size, the panel just fills the entire parent, and when I do set it, well, it can't be bigger than the size set. 
I want the size of the panels inside the BoxLayout to be dependent on the parent panel's size, and to keep their aspect ratio. Something like this example that I made.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

How can I do that?

This is my code, it's really simple.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PrezentacijaTab extends JPanel {

    private final JPanel panelZaLabel;
    private final JPanel panelZaSlajdove=new JPanel();
    private final JScrollPane scrollPaneZaSlajdove;

    public PrezentacijaTab(String labelText) {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panelZaLabel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panelZaLabel.add(new JLabel("     "+labelText),BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(panelZaLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        panelZaSlajdove.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelZaSlajdove,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        scrollPaneZaSlajdove=new JScrollPane(panelZaSlajdove);
        this.add(scrollPaneZaSlajdove,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.add(new PrezentacijaTab("Label 1"));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

`panelZaSLajdove` is where I'm storing all of my new JPanels.
User should be able to add as many panels as he wants. Think of it like  PowerPoint. The panels added are just like slides.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your code (see [mre]). Also please explain the requirement: do you want 2 JPanel's of the same size to fill the entire container?  (It can't fill the entire container and keep the aspect ratio).

Comment: I'm really sorry, this is my first ever post on SO. I think it's better now :)

Comment: No need to be sorry. We are all here to learn. I updated your code to make it more of a mre. Make sure it represents what you wanted. Please explain _ User should be able to add as many panels as he wants_  How should the added panels be laid out ? Vertically on below the other? Or _like slides_ one covering the others ?

Comment: *"The panels added are just like slides."* You might add a `Slide` object to a `JList` and use a suitable renderer such as a `SlidePanel`. Using a list component simplifies moving slides up and down the list, inserting or deleting slides anywhere in the list model as needed and offering various layouts (e.g. column verse flowing) and inbuilt selection options.

Comment: I'm not aware of any layout manager that will keep the components "aspect ratio". What exactly is on the panel. If it is like PowerPoint does that mean is it just an "image". Or does the panel contain other components? If is it other components how are they resized? I would guess you need to create an `AspectRatioLayout` layout manager.

Comment: For now, the panel only has a background image, but later it would have labels with text and images, and some other components.  I guess I will have to make my own layout manager that would support that kind of layout and resizing I want, but I'm relatively new to Java and I can't find any tutorials for that online. Thank you for all of the comments, I think I will just leave everything as it is right now until I gain the knowledge to create my own layout manager.

Comment: *"I guess I will have to make my own layout manager"* Ugh .. A single column of same-sized objects? That's easy to layout `GridLayout`, `GridBagLayout`, `BoxLayout` & `GroupLayout` can all achieve that. Figure out how to use them to achieve the effect, first, because *making a custom layout will require more expertise*.